# Joda DateTimeFormatter pattern to extract month and year

Tags: java, jodatime

I have this text 816 or 1016 and need to get month and year

```
DateTimeFormatter format =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("Myy");
DateTime instance = format.parseDateTime(expirationDate);
String.valueOf(instance.getMonthOfYear());
String.valueOf(instance.getYear());
```

Expected values should be:

For the first case 816

```
8
16
```

For the second case 1016

```
10
16
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What result are you *actually* getting?

Comment: So, you tell us.  What IS wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the input string is 4 digit i.e in case of 810 .. make it as 0810. Here is the response for the same

### Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter format =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("Myy");
org.joda.time.DateTime instance = format.parseDateTime("0810");
System.out.println(String.valueOf(instance.getMonthOfYear()));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(instance.getYear()));
```

Response:
8
2010

Hope This Helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the output you're getting is 8 16 for 816 & 0 16 for 1016.  You should really consider padding the 816 (ie. 0816) as that is the standard format for dealing with months.  Then you would use:

> DateTimeFormatter format =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMyy");